# "Go in" instead of "go inside"

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

I have a question. Actually when we're talking to a kid asking him/her to go inside,  can simply "go in" be used? Does it sound natural?

> Go in.

It is not angry command like "get inside" , just a plain neutral command.

Answer (score 2):

These are two overlapping requests/instructions, the choice of which will depend very much on the circumstances.

The tone of voice of the speaker will indicate whether a suggestion/request/instruction/command is intended.

As to context, consider two friends considering a movie outside a theatre. One might ask the other:

> Shall we go in?

meaning **shall we go to the movie?**

But outside a restaurant with interior and exterior seating, the question might be:

> Shall we go inside?

Here the real question is whether to sit inside the restaurant or outside.

Much of the time, either preposition works.

**Inside** relates more closely to a room or building.

**In** is more often used for an event - a play, a movie, an opera, a concert. Equally you would use **in** for a garden, a sports field, an outdoor market and any outdoor event.

But these are general guidelines only.

As to your kid, you could as easily speaking about **going in** (where the destination is evident), **going inside** or **going into the house**. All are natural and idiomatic.